# How to make service manager?

Tags: java, multithreading, service

I need to make a service manager that contains 4 services (example A,B,C and D), load the list of services. Service needs to have `start()` and `stop()` method and they depend on each other by this order:

- Services B and C depend on Service A
- Service D depends on Service B

And the following can be inferred:

- To start service D, service A and B need to be started
- To stop service A, service B, D and C must be stopped first
- Service B and C can be started in parallel immediately after A has started. Conversely, they can stop in parallel.

This is my code that is not working how it should work. The thing is that it's starting services by its order but only cos I put them in that order in list. I made a mess. I need help because now I don't know how to use this lines that I commented and I don't know how to stop it. Thanks for your help!

```
public class CountDown {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<String> Services = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
        Services.add("Services A");
        Services.add("Services B");
        Services.add("Services C");
        Services.add("Services D");


       final CountDownLatch Start = new CountDownLatch(4);
       final CountDownLatch Stop = new CountDownLatch(4);

    new Thread(new Service("Service A", 1000, Start, Stop, Services)).start();
    new Thread(new Service("Service B", 2000, Start, Stop, Services)).start();
    new Thread(new Service("Service C", 3000, Start, Stop, Services)).start();
    new Thread(new Service("Service D", 4000, Start, Stop, Services)).start();

    /* A.start(); // this is how it should work

      if (A.isAlive())
      {
          B.start();
          C.start();
      }

      if(B.isAlive() && A.isAlive())
      {
          D.start();
      }

      D.interrupt();
      if(D.isInterrupted())
      {
          B.interrupt();
          C.interrupt();

      }
      if(B.isInterrupted() && D.isInterrupted())
      {
          A.interrupt();
      }*/



      try { 
          Start.await();
          Stop.countDown();   
    } catch(InterruptedException ie){
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}



class Service implements Runnable{

    List<String> list;
    private final String name;
    private final int time;
    private final CountDownLatch Stop;
    private final CountDownLatch Start;


    public Service(String name, int time, CountDownLatch Start, CountDownLatch Stop, List<String> list){
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
        this.Start = Start;
        this.Stop = Stop;

        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


        try {


            Start.countDown();
           Thread.sleep(time);    
            list.add(name);


            System.out.println( name + " is Up!");


           Stop.await();

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Service.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make this a generalized system of interdependent services, you need to capture the dependencies in metadata about the service. Let us presume that you have the following data available for each service:

```
List<String> getPredecessors();
```

which returns the names of all services that must be running before this service can start. Then you have a set of services that have been started up:

```
Set<String> startedServices = new HashSet<String>();

for ( String service: Services ) {
    boolean allClear = true;
    for ( String predecessor: Service(service).getPredecessors() ) {
        if ( ! startedServices.contains(predecessor) ) {
            allClear = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( allClear ) {
        // start the service
        new Thread(new Service(service, 1000, Start, Stop, Services)).start();
        startedServices.add(service);
    }
}
```

This will start up a service only when all the services it needs are running. Now you need to iterate over all services until they are all running (or you find a deadlock).

Stopping the services is the converse problem. You can calculate the successor list from the predecessor list when you start things up. Use the same algorithm on the successor list.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for "dependency resolution algorithm". This article here has a javascript example: http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2008/08/07/dependency-resolving-algorithm/